# Someone placed 7.77 VIN tokens into my MyEtherWallet account according to EtherScan, what can I do?

Tags: tokens, wallets, myetherwallet, addresses, etherscan

I use MyEtherWallet and a Ledger for my tokens.  I check today that in Etherscan that 15 days ago some different address placed 7.77 VIN tokens and sent them to my MyEtherWallet address in my account when I connect my Ledger to it. I'm afraid someone will steal my tokens from me.

Can I change my MyEtherWallet address or get a new one? How can I transfer all my tokens from one address to a new one? Or what should I do now?

Comment: i have 1000 vin on mew but since its not erc20 token i cant transfer to exchange, how would i transfer

Comment: it would be better to ask questions separately

Answer (score 2):

They're doing an airdrop, that is, giving away tokens for free. Don't worry about it.

Comment: So if the VIN is an airdrop how'd they get my address? I didn't sign up for anything. I also received a Erc20 (UBT) Universal Bonus Token from address 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 .   What is this?

Comment: They just got it from somewhere. Ether you signed up to something else, that they got the list for, or they just went through etherscan and picked addresses that met certain criteria (actively trading altcoins?)

Comment: When you get something from address 0x0 it means it was minted and sent straight to you. Another airdrop.